# Background image not showing html+css

Tags: html, css

As the title says background image is not showing.

https://jsfiddle.net/qxL76w1v/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Omnifood</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="hero-text-box">
                <h1>Goodbye junk food. Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
                <a href="#">I’m hungry</a>
                <a href="#">Show me more </a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>


</html>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    background-image: url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh; 
}
.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
}
h1 {
   margin: 0; 
}
```

style.css

img(folder)

and in the img folder is the picture hero.jpg

I've tried to replace hero.jpg with an url photo from web but it's still not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with the line in css:

```
.header {
```

the '.' is for classes, as header is an HTML element it is not required

```
header {
  background-image: url("img/hero.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check to see if your img folder is in another folder....you may have to go back or forward. Also, put single quotes around your URL path

back example: background-image: url('../images/stock1.jpg');

forward example: background-image: url('/images/stock1.jpg');